# How to dump my data from excel sheet to Mongodb with Java

Tags: java, mongodb, excel-2010

I just need to read my `excel` file, which will be containing n no. of columns, and push those data into my `MongoDB` with `Java` programming.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Just export to CSV and read it as text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using Apache POI for spreadsheets? They have various [examples](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents) on how to read/write Excel files, for instance:

```
// Get content of cells
// import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
for (Row row : sheet1) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        CellReference cellRef = new CellReference(row.getRowNum(), cell.getColumnIndex());
        System.out.print(cellRef.formatAsString());
        System.out.print(" - ");

        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                    System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
                } else {
                    System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                }
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                System.out.println(cell.getCellFormula());
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, for mapping the contents to MongoDB you would have to use the [Java driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/?_ga=1.103574658.384128272.1429625278). I couldn't give you much information on that as I've only ever used the Python driver, but the introductory manual seems quite easy to follow.